# String literal type as default argument value

Tags: generics, typescript, types, redux

I'm trying to prevent a cast inside my `redux` reducer by using an [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) in `TypeScript`. I managed to get a somewhat workable solution.

#### Code

This is the helper type guard function I'm using:

```
export function isAction<A extends Action>(action: Action, type: A['type']): action is A {
    return action.type === type;
}
```

An I'm using it like this inside my reducer:

```
if (isAction<actions.LoginAction>(action, types.LOGIN)) {
    // access action.payload here
}
```

And the action interface (`actions.LoginAction` above) is defined as followed:

```
export interface LoginAction
{
    type: typeof types.LOGIN,
    payload: {
        username: string,
        password: string;
    }
}
```

And the action type is declared as:

```
export const LOGIN = "authentication/login";
```

#### Question

How can I rewrite the `isAction` method to prevent having to specify the action type twice (once inside the action interface, and once in the call to isAction).

I have tried many variants of the following, but nothing will compile.

```
function isAction<A extends Action>(action: Action, type = A['type']): action is A {
    return action.type === type;
}
```

The compiler has the information, but I can't seem to be able to express what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get excellent type support within a reducer without having to do user-defined type guarding.  I type my redux bits and pieces like this, and the typescript compiler is smart enough to work out the correct action shape inside each branch of the switch statement.  Hope this is helpful.  There is more information on string literal types at https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html - they were the key to getting redux typing working for me.

```
// Constants/Types
// This is a string literal type, meaning that no other string
// will pass type checking
export type LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';

// Generic action type, for typing actions themselves
// This is just to make typing actions quicker/easier, I 
// merge declare it on the redux module.
export interface TypedAction<T> extends Redux.Action {
    type: T;
}

// Which is used to create typed actions
// E.g. with a payload
export interface LoginAction extends TypedAction<LOGIN> {
    payload: {
        username: string;
        password: string;
    }
}

// Or without a payload
export type LogoutAction = TypedAction<LOGIN>;

// I typically then export a union type of all the actions that a
// reducer will be dealing with
export type HandledActions = LoginAction | LogoutAction;

// The reducer state is typed...
export interface StateShape {
    currentUser: string;
}

const initialState: StateShape = {
    currentUser: '';
}

// And the reducer action is typed using the union type from above
const reducer: Redux.Reducer<StateShape> = (state = initialState, action: HandledActions) => {
    // Within the switch statement the action will have the correct type
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOGIN:
            // Passes type checks, code autocomplete gives correct payload
            const { username } = action.payload;
            return { currentUser: username };
        case LOGOUT:
            // Code autocomplete gives no payload here
            return initialState;
        default:
             return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out tomorrow and mark it as an answer if it works :)

Comment: Works like a charm! I think I was overthinking this :)